# scatterplot problems with x-axis not being readable

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, x-axis

```
ggplot(data = Covid_data_filtered, mapping = aes(x = Pneumonia.Deaths, y = Covid_Deaths))+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Change `aes(x = Pneumonia.Deaths, y = Covid_Deaths)` to `aes(x = as.numeric(Pneumonia.Deaths), y = Covid_Deaths)`

Comment: To expand a bit on Phil's comment, because `Pneumonia.Deaths` is a character or factor variable, ggplot2 is giving you a discrete x-axis. If it is a factor instead of a character, you should use `as.numeric(as.character(Pneumonia.Deaths))`.

Comment: I tried both of them & this is what i got & now a chart isn't popping up at all.    ggplot(data = Covid_data_filtered, mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(Pneumonia.Deaths)), y = Covid_Deaths))+geom_point()
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Covid_Deaths' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
> ggplot(data = Covid_data_filtered, mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(Pneumonia_Deaths)), y = Covid_Deaths)+geom_point()
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.